# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm developing an application with sqlalchemy and I'm constantly getting a no such table error when I try to add data to a table. However, such a table exists. Here is my code in models.py:

```
DATABASE_NAME = 'test_task_db.sqlite'
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()


class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(50))


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    fio = Column(TEXT)
   datar = Column(DATE)
   id_role = (Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

main.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "test_task_db.sqlite")
with Session(engine) as session:
    newUser = Users(fio=name,
                 datar=datetime(2012, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10),
                 id_role=randint(1, 2))

    session.add(newUser)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your connection String for sqlite. On sqlite3, for :memory: database, you may pass an [empty connection string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlite) :

```
sqlite://
```

You don't need to specify :memory: at the end.

If you want to specify a table, then you do something like :

```
sqlite://{path}/dbname.db:
```

The number of slashes depend on your path,
you should add three slashes for relative paths :

```
sqlite:///./dbname.db
```

Four slashes for absolute paths, for example if you want to give an absolute path called "/var/dir/"

```
sqlite:////var/dir/dbname.db
```

I've also seen db names have a .db extension, did you specifically modify that?

---

Here's a [version of a FastAPI app](https://github.com/jcroyoaun/user-api/commit/243f512d0506c0b0bccddb4b34ccc728d53c9f76) I was connecting to sqlite3 so you can get an idea of what to try next. I have since migrated it to postgersql, however I'm linking a revision history with the older version. I'd suggest you to test creating the DB on the project directory so you can add the "." relative path connection string and lastly, make sure that the DB name and the extension you're providing in your models.py is correct.